# Brownout detector triggered

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide, esp32, electronics

I'm running a pretty basic setup. When I run a small program just doing some `serial.println`, it works fine, when I try to do operations that needs more power, the brownout detector gets triggered. I'm running my chip on an ok buff power supply so I don't get what the problem is.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The ESP typically runs on 3.3 Volt, not 3.0 Volt.

<strike>Secondly, it looks like the board has a voltage regulator, all power goes through the voltage regulator. If that's the case the voltage you need to supply must be lower that the drop-out voltage of the regulator (which is typically around a volt).</strike>

Comment: the thing you see on the PCB is a 10k resistance, from power to the EN pin as required, i havent added any voltage regulators

Comment: (the big blue thing is just the USB to UART, it doesnt draw any power or provide any power)

Comment: and btw the operating range of the ESP32 is 3v to 3.6v,

Comment: I mistook the 3-pin part in the schematic for a linear voltage regulator. I know the ESP can run on a lower voltage. But since you were having power related problems it might be a idea to at least check whether the problem remains when supplying 3.3V. 3.0 is the minimum voltage the ESP runs at, and there might be some resistance in the wires, and breadboard, that could cause a high enough voltage drop when the ESP is drawing more current for the ESP to brown out.

Comment: Why is the USB to serial board connected to your 3 volt supply? Also make sure your breadboards power rails (blue and red) don't have a split in the middle. Some breadboards have this "feature".

Comment: for some reason the usb to uart need power suply,

Comment: im not home atm but running it on 3.3v will probably not change anything

Comment: tho the weird thing is that it consistently brownout evry second time